# How to let multiple threads write on the same file

Tags: c#, multithreading, io

I have got a text file called "vholders.txt".

I am making multiple threads as you can see here ,those threads work with their own given data and at last they write their own output to the `vholders.txt`. But I get IO exception cause file is being used by another thread. So how can I write to `vholders.txt` file without colliding with other threads.The sequence of which thread should write first doesn't matter.

this is my code:

```
public void execute()
    {
        for(int x=0;x<entered_length;x++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PooledProc),x);
        }

    }
    private void PooledProc(object x_)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        //does the processing...and assign output its value...
        /*this is where I get error*/
        StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("vholders.txt"); //error, file is being used by another process
        sw.WriteLine(output);
        sw.Close();
        /*Now how can I write the output value to the text file vholders.txt without getting IO Exception*/
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of multithreaded programming! You're going to need a lock, aka semaphore, to do what you want.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, what? everything you said almost went over the head. Explain please :)

Comment: They're terms you should be able to Google :-).

Comment: okie dokie!, plus if you know any answer to my question or modify my question to a better looking question then that would be great.

Comment: Alternatively, make PooledProc() [synchronized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C# you can use [ReaderWriteLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) class to allow a single write operation in your file (and multiple readers, if this is needed).

Also, to maximize performance you can have asynchronous operations using [Asynchronous File I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.100).aspx) (you can have some processing while the I/O operations are being done).

However, before diving into these concepts, some things must be clarified in order to obtain the simplest solution for your problem:

1. do you have any readers from your file while it is being written?
2. is this a continuous process or it happens just several times per day?
3. are you processing large data (GB?)

If the answer is `No` to all the above questions, you might consider doing all the processing in memory and writing all the [output at once.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To all your questions,the answer is no, but sometimes output can size upto MBs thats not a problem but I am trying to keep memory usage least.So, what should I do?

Comment: As already suggested in a previous comment use some locking mechanism, so that 2+ threads do not write in your file in the same time. I have suggested `ReaderWriteLock` class, as it seems to be designed exactly for what you need.

Comment: Thanks man your suggestion worked. I am using the very first one (ReaderWriteLock)